# Regex: fixed length without taking "-" into account

Tags: regex

I am trying to formulate a regular expression to match strings with a certain length, but not counting the "-" character (but may have more than one.

For example:

```
123-45 12345 123456 abc 123a4... (very long string)
```

desired results:

```
123-45
12345
```

Comment: could you explain your question clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match 5-digit words, allowing any number of intervening, but not leading/trailing, dashes:

```
(?<!-)\b(\d-*){4}\d\b(?!-)
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/mlaXqgXVrH) showing matching each of:

```
123-45 12345 1-2-3-4-5 1----2345
```

but none of:

```
1234a5 123456 1234 -12345 123-45-
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex here. You could do the below which is in pseudo-code.

```
var len = str.replace("-", "").length;
if(len > 5 || len < 7){
  // valid
}
```

Just remove every `-` and then check for `length`

Comment: I need a regex. Why? Because it's easier for me. For example, I also filter some characters (digits), I pull out a set of valid sequences from one long string (with some separation between them: profit, jump line, etc.). You can do anything with the code, I know, and so it did until now, it's not very nice. Is your answer is that it is impossible in regex?